# Updating HTML title after AJAX page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html-title

When I load new pages via AJAX I need to of course update the HTML title to match the new page. The code below is something I have used successfully in past projects but for some reason it's not working here.

```
ajaxLoad = function(html) {
    init();
    // init google map
    initMap();
    // change html title
    var HTMLtitle = $(".content > section:first-of-type").attr("data-title");
    $(document).prop('title', HTMLtitle);
    document.title = HTMLtitle;
    // Used for popState event (back/forward browser buttons)
    changedPage = true;
  }
```

This is just a part of the javascript and you can view the rest in context if needed on the live site.

**Live site:** http://dma.nz/practice/

Click the top right links in the main nav to go to other pages. In my testing the title seems to update sometimes on the first page change but then never works on subsequent page changes. Most times it doesn't work at all and the title never updates. All of those top level pages have the proper HTML title defined in the data attribute, but some part of the function is failing and not updating the title and I cannot find where it's borked.

**Can anyone please offer help on what I'm doing wrong or propose a better way to update the title on each AJAX page load?**

Comment: Check your console, you have an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks I'm aware of that. I think it's something to do with my google maps API code, which I've been struggling a bit with to make work on a page loaded by AJAX. Would that error, even if unrelated, cause my HTML title updating to fail?

Comment: what is  `$(document).prop('title', HTMLtitle);` used for?

Comment: @BenekLisefski it's possible it's interfering with execution of further code, yes. It depends on how you have your JS structured.

Comment: @madalinivascu this code is borrowed from a tutorial on integrating AJAX page transition with Craft CMS and that was part of it that was there and I didn't question. Looks to me like just another way of saying "document.title = HTMLtitle;". Probably don't need both but would it hurt to keep both?

Answer (score 1):

As you're aware of the javascript error in initMap function

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null

That exception breaks all your javascript below that line. Just fix it and your code will work, just like your main page: http://dma.nz/practice/

Comment: I'm trying to fix that but haven't found a solution yet. Seems in order to get one part of the site to work I have to break another! It's proving difficult to get everything working together at once. I'll report back once I figure out how to solve that error. Thanks.

Comment: I've temporarily disabled the part that was throwing this error and it looks like it probably will solve the problem. Sorry for the stupid question. Should have thought to resolve the error first.